# How should a buried water hose be winterized?

Tags: winterizing

It's easy enough to winterize the green hose in the picture below. The watertap connects to a T-joint. The green hose stays in the backyard, and the white one scurries somewhere in hiding to reach the front yard. To winterize the green (backyard) 50ft hose, I just took the whole thing (water inside and all) to the garage but left this short connecting segment where it is (as pictured).

Removing the white hose appears to be a serious job. Is it necessary to winterize such a hose at all or is such a white hose meant to withstand frost? If it's necessary to winterize it by blowing the water out of it while it's still in place, what kind of pump should I be looking for? Would some "shop vac" type of tool have an option to blow rather than suck air, and would there be some connectors on the market to do the trick?

[image: buried-water-hose]

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely blow out the water to winterize. Anything in that hose will definitely freeze. There may be enough space in the line to get lucky and make it through a winter, but it'll eventually ruin that hose and replacing it looks like it would be annoying. They make adapters for air compressors to do this very thing.

You can rent or borrow an air compressor and use [something like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0055Q6CRO) to connect (sometimes called a blow out hose or blow out plug)

Comment: How about just pouring some non-toxic RV antifreeze in it until it comes out the other end? A $5 jug of antifreeze must be cheaper than renting an air compressor. (100 feet of 1/2" hose will hold around 1 gallon of liquid, 3/4" hose will hold twice that amount)

Comment: Would an electric (120V) mattress pump do the trick? If not, what is the type of pump I'd be looking for? The other end is connected to two sprinklers. After searching for "air compressor" at amazon and home depot: would an air compressor meant for "bike/auto" be suitable?

Comment: @Calaf No, but a shop compressor could get most of the water out.  Really, you just need a tank of air 5-10+ gallons that you can discharge through the line for a couple full tanks.  Also, the 1/4" quick connect fitting really will restrict the air flow; I recommend if you have the know how to use a 3/8" quick connect, or no quick connect with a full port valve.  We have a gas air compressor, 9 gallon tank, with 3/8" quick connects, 3/8 air hose, that has a hard time blowing out 1" sprinkler lines on our property.

Comment: Personally I'd rather not have antifreeze, even non-toxic, in a water line - but that would be better than doing nothing. 

Like @Damon said — you need a shop compressor, not a pump. Be sure you use 150psi or less or you could blow the hose out. You can get a small compressor for $100 and it's a good investment to have around the house in general — good for small nail guns and other air tools, painting, car tires, and just blowing dust out. Alternatively, it would probably cost you $30 to rent a small one for a day.